# IE11 Conditional CSS Comment does not work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, conditional-comments

I have tried several conditional formats as seen in different sites but can't seem to get this to work. Browser version is IE 11.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title></title>
<link href="CSS/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="CSS/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--[if !IE]><!--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/login.css" /><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><!--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/loginIE.css" /><!--<![endif]-->
```

I already changed the format. removing Bootstrap and Fontawesome CSS but still not working. I even changed/removed the doctype and meta values but nothing worked. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no Conditional comments for IE10+, take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
>   10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5. This means that Conditional Comments are now
>   treated as regular comments, just like in other browsers. This change
>   can impact pages written exclusively for Windows Internet Explorer or
>   pages that use browser sniffing to alter their behavior in Internet
>   Explorer.

you can try using IE hacks for IE10 and IE11

something like this:

```css
/*IE10 and IE11*/

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .selector { property:value; }
}
```

Comment: Oh shoot!! I should have googled IE11 browser comments. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem :) See updated answer for a possible solution ;)

Comment: Did that just now. It just said that I had to wait for 10 minutes before I can choose it as the answer to the question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[Conditional comments are no longer supported after IE10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer 10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and compliance with HTML5.